# Correctly implementing a search function

Tags: asp.net, linq, contains, iqueryable, anonymous-types

I have a search function that searches against a `user table` and a `Vehicle Registration table`. There is a one to many relationship between the tables.

The `VehicleNumb`is a collection of number where I've inserted '-' to make it more readable. Keep in mind that in my DB, the numbers do not have dashes.

So when I'm searching, I removed the '-' and replaced it with an empty string.

So for example, if I have 12345678 in my table, I would have placed a '-' like this 12-345678. So when I'm searching for 12-345678, I expect to get the 
the user result.

The issue I'm encountering is that I can not get any result back. Where am I going wrong?

```cs
public IQueryable <MyModel> Method(string search)
{
    var userResult = _context.User.Select(u => new MyModel()
    {
      UserName = u.UserName,
      FullName = u.FullName,
      Status = u.MStatus,
      VehicleNumb = u.Vehicle
                     .Where(v => v.Registration.VehicleNumb.Any() 
                            && v.Registration.VehicleNumb != null)
                           .Select(x => v.Registration.VehicleNumb.Insert(2, "-"))
    });

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search.Replace("-", "")))
    {
         foreach(var item in userResult)
         {
             foreach(var item2 in item.VehicleNumb)
             {
              userResult = userResult
                  .Where(x => item2.Replace("-", "").Contains(search.Replace("-", "")));
             }
         }
        return userResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code yet?

Comment: Yes I have. The result doesn't return anything. Im not sure where I'm going wrong.

Comment: If you are getting no results, that hints at a problem with your query, please post your expected output as well so that I can get a better image here.

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: I think it would help if you added your Vehicle model to the question.